One of two flask apps (one that was started later) on same domain does not work
I am trying to host two bots on one local machine. For simplicity, let's call one "Bot A" and other "Bot B".
I made route for one as "mydomain.io/a", for other as "mydomain.io/b":
bot = TeleBot(TOKEN)
app = Flask(__name__)
bot.remove_webhook()
bot.set_webhook('mydomain.io/a')

@app.route('/a', methods=['POST'])
def tovc_webhook():
    if request.headers.get('content-type') == 'application/json':
        json_string = request.get_data().decode('utf-8')
        update = types.Update.de_json(json_string)
        bot.process_new_updates([update])
        return ''
    else:
        abort(403)

...sum working code...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()


And same code for another one, but bot.set_webhook('mydomain.io/b'), @app.route('/b', methods=['POST']) etc.
Any of the bots work by itself, but when i try to start both at the same time, - one, that was started first continues to work, but later one does not do anything.
(triple-checked that routes and webhooks and etc are not same, basically triple-checked everything)
Later I've come up with an idea. I've created one more file, "C.py":
from a import bot as abot
from b import bot as bbot 
app = Flask(__name__)

abot.remove_webhook()
abot.set_webhook('mydomain.io/a')

bbot.remove_webhook()
bbot.set_webhook(mydomain.io/b)

@app.route('/a', methods=['POST'])
def tovc_webhook():
    if request.headers.get('content-type') == 'application/json':
        json_string = request.get_data().decode('utf-8')
        update = types.Update.de_json(json_string)
        abot.process_new_updates([update])
        return ''
    else:
        abort(403)

@app.route('/b', methods=['POST'])
def tovc_webhook():
    if request.headers.get('content-type') == 'application/json':
        json_string = request.get_data().decode('utf-8')
        update = types.Update.de_json(json_string)
        bbot.process_new_updates([update])
        return ''
    else:
        abort(403)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()

i.e. transferred and merged some of code of both bots into C.py.
Surprisingly, that did work, but I got two more problems with that.
Problem 1 - I can't start bots separately now.
Problem 2 - for some reason, exceptions and error don't show up anymore, as like I did try: <code> except: pass.
What am i doing wrong?
Also, please, don't ask why I need two bots at the same time on ngrok. Trust me.
(oh and also I don't want to make bots on different ports for one reason)

It looks like you're running both apps on the same port. Recall that when you run a Flask app you're also running a (simplified) web server that listens for requests, routes those requests to your code/app, and serves the result back to the web client. You can't have more than one (TCP) server listening on the same port of a host, and by default Flask apps listen on port 5000 so when you run the second app it fails because port 5000 is already in use by the first.
The simple solution is to run each app on separate ports. This post describes how to start a Flask app on a non-default port: How do I get Flask to run on port 80?
If you want both apps running without having to specify a different port for each then you'll either need to combine the apps together or configure them to run under a more production-capable server (e.g. nginx, Apache httpd, gunicorn).
Here are some links to get you started down that path:

How do I setup files to run multiple flask (nginx, gunicorn) applications on one server? (specify separate ports)
How to host multiple flask apps under a single domain hosted on nginx?

